# Pandas join dataframes by multiple key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 different dataframes that I want to join, using label and window as keys.

DataFrame1

```
Window  Label  FeatA
123      1        h
123      2        f
```

DataFrame2

```
Window  Label  FeatB
123      1      d 
123      2      s
```

DataFrame3

```
Window  Label  FeatC
123     1       d
123     2       c
```

Result

```
Window  Label  FeatA  FeatB  FeatC
123      1       h      d       d
123      2       f      s       c
```

I know how to join dataframes using `pandas.concat` but don't know how to specify keys. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can set `Window` as index and use `pd.concat()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure pandas answer using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df.set_index(['Window', 'Label']) for df in [df1_, df2_, df3_]],
          axis=1).reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `merge` function for joining tables, for your case, since you have multiple data frames to join, you can put them into a list and then use the `reduce` from `functools` to merge them one by one:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = ['Window', 'Label']), [df1, df2, df3])

#  Window   Label   FeatA   FeatB   FeatC
# 0   123       1       h      d        d
# 1   123       2       f      s        c
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
In[44]:df.combine_first(df1).combine_first(df2)[['Window','Label','FeatA','FeatB','FeatC']]
Out[44]: 
   Window  Label FeatA FeatB FeatC
0     123      1     h     d     d
1     123      2     f     s     c
```

or you can use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In[30]:df.merge(df1,on=['Window','Label']).merge(df2,on=['Window','Label'])
Out[30]: 
   Window  Label FeatA FeatB FeatC
0     123      1     h     d     d
1     123      2     f     s     c
```

Comment: `combine_first` is matching on `index` and `columns`.  It will produce a dataframe that has an index that is `a.index.union(b.index)` and like wise for the columns.  if you have `a = pd.DataFrame([], list('ab'), list('AB'))` and 
`b = pd.DataFrame([], list('cd'), list('CD'))` then `a.combine_first(b)` will be a 4x4 dataframe.  The point is, your answer is ignoring the fact that the OP wants to join on `['Window', 'Label']` and is actually matching on the given integer index.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks for pointing I have lot to learn.